# Run Macro on specific static file when macro workbook is opened

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a VBA Macro that I need to run on a CSV file that always has the same name and is always in the same location. Is there a way I can get it to automatically run the macro on the specified csv file as soon as the macro file is opened? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, pop it in the Workbook_Open event.  To do this open VBA, make sure you can see the Project Explorer, double click on ThisWorkbook, click the drop down that currently says General and change it to  Workbook and put your code in there.

Comment: This is assuming your macro is in Excel.  Similar for Word, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have it so that when the macro workbook is opened it automatically runs the macro, however how do I get it to automatically run the macro on a separate csv file? Thanks again

Comment: Well, you need to tell Excel what the name of the csv file is.  So perhaps edit your macro so that it first opens a different text file containing the name of your csv file.  Then it processes that csv as normal.